# Resize UITextView to the size of its text and condense the size if it is greater than a height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextview

I am trying to make a tableview that is similar to apps like facebook, where it shows the post's texts and if the post is too large, it will cut the size down and have a "Read More" button. I have looked at many different solutions for resizing UITextViews to the height of their text, however none of them are solving my problem. My problem is only existing with large posts. When I have a large post, my function that returns the height of the textView should return the maxHeight of the posts before being expanded. This part works. However, when I click my "Read More" button, I have a massive amount of white space at the bottom of the full textView. Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return heightForTextOfRow(indexPath.row) + PostCell.additionalVertSpaceNeeded
}

func heightForTextOfRow(row: Int) -> CGFloat {
     var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, prototypeTextViewWidth, CGFloat.max))
     let post = data[row]

     textView.text = (post.postText as NSString).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
     textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
     textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
     textView.font = PostCell.textViewFont
     textView.frame.size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(prototypeTextViewWidth, CGFloat.max))
     if textView.frame.size.height > maxHeight && !post.seeMore {
         return maxHeight
     } else {
         return textView.frame.size.height
     }

}
```

Some explanations of the code:

- data is an array of Posts (the only thing that is relevant about the class Post in this case is that it has a property postText and seeMore.)
- PostCell.textViewFont is a constant in one of my classes that returns the font I am using (System font size 13)
- PostCell.additionalVertSpaceNeeded is a constant that returns the height of all other elements in my prototype cell except for the UITextView
- prototypeTextViewWidth is defined as tableView.frame.width - 16 (16 is the value of the margins added together)
- maxHeight is the max height of a post that does not want to show the full post (currently defined as tableView.frame.height * 0.625 - PostCell.additionalVertSpaceNeeded)
- seeMore is a Bool property of Post that tells whether or not to show the full post or whether to show just a portion of the post (true shows full post, false shows a post of height maxHeight)

Any help would be appreciated... I have tried many solutions to resizing the UITextView and all have this same problem. Thanks in advance!